# Javascript round up values

Tags: javascript

My variable having like this

```
       var silver_weight=1.9327400000000003;
       //Rounded silver_weight
       result_final = Math.ceil(silver_weight);
       output is 2
```

So output coming 2 because ceil will return nearest integer.But i need here only round off when 4th decimal value is greater than 7.My output need like this 1.933

Comment: That will also return only nearest integer

Comment: Do you really mean to round up only when the 4th decimal digit is greater or equal to 7?

Comment: Yes i Need on 4th decimal is greater than or equal to 7

Comment: Then you need something like `Math.floor(silver_weight * 1000 + 0.3) / 1000` rather than the answers here. This will mean that 1.93265 will round down to 1.932

Answer (score 2):

`parseFloat(silver_weight.toFixed(3))`

Comment: Any chance of floating-point oddities with this? To be totally safe from that, you could return a string.

Comment: There are definitely some weird things that can happen with `toFixed`, like: `0.45.toFixed(1) == "0.5"` but `0.35.toFixed(1) == "0.3"`. But that's floating point math for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round()` like this:

```
Math.round(1.9327400000000003 * 1000) / 1000
```

**Explanation:**

`Math.round()` will round the number to 0 decimal places but if you need more, first multiply the number by **10^n**, round it and then divide it by **10^n** where **n** is the number of decimal places you need.

Comment: Works Great but when use for this 2.1635999999999997 am getting 2.164 ,but i need 4th decimal is greater or equal to 7

Comment: So if I understand you corectly: You want to round to 3 decimal points but round the last decimal point up if the 4th one is greater than 7 or down if it's less than 7? `12.3456 => 12.345` and  `1.3457 => 1.346`?

Comment: Yes thats correct i need to point up 3rd decimal only 4th decimal is greater than or equal to 7

Comment: You could probably do something with string manipulation. Round it to 4 decimal places, split in on the decimal point (to get the decimals only) detect if the 4th number is greater than zero and if it is, increment the 3rd one by 1.

Comment: Or just use the function I gave as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Math.round(weight * 1000)/1000